# Too few arguments in PendingResourceRegistration::name()? Por qué?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

Estoy haciendo un simple form para enviar datos a una BBDD, pero cuando le doy a submit aparece el siguiente error.

No entiendo porque esta apareciendo la verdad :S

> Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Routing\PendingResourceRegistration::name(), 1 passed in C:\laragon\www\envio-curriculum\routes\web.php on line 18 and exactly 2 expected

`web.php`

```
<?php

Route::resource('/', 'enviarCurriculum\EnviarCurriculumController')->only(['index', 'create', 'store']);
```

`EnviarCurriculumController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\enviarCurriculum;

use App\EnviarCurriculum;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\Http\Requests\StoreEnviarCurriculumPost;


class EnviarCurriculumController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view ('enviar_curriculum');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view ('enviar_curriculum', ['post' => new EnviarCurriculum()]);
    }

    public function store(StoreEnviarCurriculumPost $request)
    {
        EnviarCurriculum::create($request->validated());

        return back() -> with('status', '¡Post creado con éxito!');
    }
}
```

`enviar_curriculum.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="{{ route("EnviarCurriculum.store") }}" method="POST">
        @csrf

        <h4>Datos Personales</h4>    
        <small class="pull-right">sin espacios, ni guiones</small>
        <br>
        <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="nif" id="nif" class="form-control" placeholder="* NIF/NIE/Pasaporte" maxlength="20" required data-error="Por favor rellene este campo">

//4 inputs más con nombre, apellido1, apellido2 y sexo) 
// Lo pongo así porque sino no me deja postear la duda por "mucho código"

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar"> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Tengo en un fillable llamado EnviarCurriculum.php a parte declarado lo siguiente:

protected $fillable = ['nif', 'nombre', 'apellido1', 'apellido2', 'sexo'];

Lo dejo así porque no me deja escribir más líneas de código -_-

Comment: comparte el request

Comment: parce que tienes problema con el name de la ruta, haz un php artisan r:l y mira cual es el name de la ruta store